# Missing dependences sybase

Tags: c++, sybase, freetds

i need to compile a project who requires tdspp(who uses a sybase), when i compile and install the source  of tdspp(downloaded via git), it's ok, but the main project requires this library, and when i try to compile, get the next errors:

```
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_results' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_connect' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_exit' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `cs_ctx_alloc' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_init' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `cs_ctx_drop' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_cancel' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_cmd_drop' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_con_props' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_con_drop' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_con_alloc' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_close' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_command' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_send' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_cmd_alloc' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_res_info' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_fetch' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_bind' sin definir
//usr/local/lib/libtds++.so: referencia a `ct_describe' sin definir
```

( "..." reference to '...' undefined)

This functions are defined by sybase (recently i add the next modules libdbd-freetds, libdbi-dev, libopendbx1-sybase, freetds-common, freetds-dev, tdsodbc,  libpthread-workqueue-dev, libpthread-workqueue0, and i think i'ts no problem of the dependences of tdspp).

In the makefile i have the next line to include tdspp

```
  -I/home/artur/projects/value/trunk/tdspp -L/home/artur/projects/value/tdspp -ltds++
```

How i can (or how i will) add correctly the library tdspp to my project.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have the the CT-library libs available. Stuff won't work without those.

Comment: ok, was easy but not intutive, the solution was, include the library explicit in the makefile(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libct.so.4.0.0)